# to add the background image in the style sheet in ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby

I tried these commands but i cannot access the background image which i stored in both places,  
            app/assets/images/pw_maze_black_2X.png
            public/image/pw_maze_black_2X.png

```
 background-image: image-url('pw_maze_black_2X.png');

 background-image: image-url("pw_maze_black_2X.png");

 background:image-url('pw_maze_black_2X.png');

 background-image:url('pw_maze_black_2X.png');

 background-image:url(../images/macbook-pro.png);

 background: url( asset-path('pw_maze_black_2X.png') );

 background:url('/app/assets/images/pw_maze_black_2X.png');

 background: url('/assets/pw_maze_black_2X.png');

 background:url(../image/pw_maze_black_2X.png) left top no-repeat;

 background-image: image-url('/public/images/pw_maze_black_2X.png');

 background_image:url('/public/images/pw_maze_black_2X.png');
```

i changed in config/environments/production.rb

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

and added the code given below:

```
 config.assets.precompile = ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
```

i am using rails version 4.2.4

thank you in advance

Comment: Is your problem in production only ? Have you run `rake assets:precompile` in production ?

Comment: Even after using this   rake assets:precompile   i can't able to view the background images